# Laravel how to get auth user id on cronjob

Tags: php, laravel

I run a cronjob every minute and data returne, i save on db in a table `notification`. But here i need to save also `user_id`. I mean i know we can not find `Auth::user()->id` on cronjob but how can we get this user id?

```
 public function handle(ReminderEventServices $reminderServices)
    {
        // return 0;
        // $getLastReminders = $reminderServices->ReminderEvent(); 
        $getLastReminders = Reminder::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

        return app('App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController')->store($getLastReminders);
}
```

I have send request to Notification controller , hoping there i can use there `Auth` but i was wrong.

```
    public function store($getLastReminders)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        
        foreach($getLastReminders as $reminder) {
            if (!Notification::where('title', $reminder->title)->exists()) {
                $notification = Notification::create([
                    'title'         => $reminder->title,
                    'user_id'       => $user_id,
                    'description'   => $reminder->description,
                    'remindTime'    => $reminder->remindTime
                ]);
            }

            event(new ReminderEvent($reminder));
        }
    }
```

Comment: A notification that is always for the current user should simply not be in a cronjob. The cronjob is run in the background without the context of the user. If you use a [Laravel Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) which is run in the background you can supply a user-id.

Comment: What exactly do you need the logged in users ids for? Cron/CLI knows nothing about users logged in on the web part of your site.

Comment: @brombeer I save notification i get from pusher event on a table called notification. And want  foreach user to show only notification who belongs to user

Comment: @PeterKrebs But my notification does not run when user make an action but every minute check if a datetime is different form some other record

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: The cronjob still has no idea about the user session so you simply cannot get the user id you are looking for there. Instead you could create an API to create/read/update/delete notifications via AJAX, for example.

Comment: I found a solution. I save user id on reminders table and copy them to notification table when records created to notifications. But still i have one problem. When event added from pusher , he still show to all users couse is on public chanel i think. i does not uinderstand pusher very well. I think i need a good tutorial or documentation

Answer (score 1):

You should try another approach - the cron job is not supposed to handle users in that way. Consider trying an event listener or an observer instead. I've included the [link to Laravels documentation on events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#introduction) for your convienience.